# Does SQL Server 2008 compress the results sent back to my web server?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, compression

I have a typical reporting application:

`Large report <-- HTTP Compression --> ASP.NET Web Server <-- ??? --> SQL Server 2008`

Since I have so much (repetitive) data to send to the client, I would like both network hops to have compression.

Is there a transport-level compression setting for SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard data transfer is optimized between your DB and application.  If you think you really need a more efficient solution, you could build a CLR function inside your SQL Server that will compress your data.  That way you will (1) reduce the bandwidth between the websever and db server and (2) via pre-processing inside the db server, you can lower web server processing by just streaming your pre-processed data through your web server and to the Request.

Comment: Compressing via CLR wouldn't server any real purpose. If you're talking about compressing the network stream itself that's not possible via SQL CLR.
As i understood you want to call a webrequest directly from the sql server? again that a bad idea because it opens it up to different kinds of security threats.

Answer (score 2):

no, there isn't. The TDS data stream is somewhat compressed but that's it.
If the db to web server presents a real problem then consider adding caching for relatively static data. no need to prematurely optimize this.